# Scons: command-line build variables without restrictions on allowed values

Tags: scons

Used Scons version: 3.0.1 (for historic reasons)

I want to add a command-line build variable in my Scons script which is not limited by which values it expects. Both EnumVariable and ListVariable require you to provide a list of allowed values or elements.
I want a variable that (just like a C++ define can be passed to g++ via -Dfoo=bar (or at least -Dfoo_bar) ) can be passed to the Scons script.

Anything like

```
scons my_define=foo_bar
```

or

```
scons my_define=foo=bar,gnarl=argl
```

or

```
scons my_define=foo my_define=bar
```

would work.

I did not find anything like that in the [user guide](https://scons.org/doc/3.0.1/HTML/scons-user.html) or searching via Google.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's in the users guide at

https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#idp140637539360912

While there are validated variable types provided by the various `vars.Add*()` methods. You can have a non-validated variable by just using plain `vars.Add()`

Here's an example from the manpage.

```
vars.Add('CC', help='The C compiler')
```